# Upgrading Flutter Web Application: Resolving Deprecated API Usage

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The console message:

> The webOnlyWarmupEngine API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `bootstrapEngine` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
> The webOnlySetPluginHandler API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `setPluginHandler` from `dart:ui_web` instead.
> The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.

How and where am I supposed to make this change?